# has_many after a has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Here are my current models...

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :albums
  has_many :follows
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :follows
end

class Album < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Follow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows
  has_many :artists, -> { uniq }, through: :follows
end
```

What I want to be able to do is get all the `Albums` for a user.

I can get the artists easily (`@user.artists`) but what I'm having trouble getting are all the albums of those artists.

`Artists` are associated with `Users` through the `Follows` model.

Would love to be able to do something like `@users.albums` or `@users.artists.albums`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `user has_many :artists` and `artist has_many :albums`

Just create a `has_many` association in `User` model with `album :through artists`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows
  has_many :artists, -> { uniq }, through: :follows
  has_many :album, through: :artists
end
```

Now you can use `@user.albums`